# How to put the message got from jdbc to rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration

In the [spring integration reference on JDBC Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html)
it has the following code to get the records out of a table and convert them into message and sent them to a channel. But my system is rabbitmq so I want the message from jdbc stored in rabbitmq and consumed by rabbitmq client. How to do that using spring integration and spring rabbitmq?

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from item where status=2"
    channel="target" data-source="dataSource"
    update="update item set status=10 where id in (:id)" />
```

I know there are AMQP Backed Message Channels, and defined as below.

```
<int-amqp:channel id="p2pChannel"/>
```

But how to put them together? So that the message created from a table will be stored in a rabbitmq queue?

update: I used the following code:

```
<bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/example"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="oracle"/>
</bean>

<int-amqp:channel id="myMessageChannel_test"/>


<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from my_files where message_created=0"
                                  channel="myMessageChannel_test" data-source="dataSource"
                                  update="update my_files set message_created=1 where file_id in (:file_id)">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000">
        <int:transactional/>
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

But it complains:

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for amqp-channel 'myMessageChannel_test'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel.java:197)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:737)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel.java:181)
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2014-12-30 19:23:18.985  WARN 29203 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:802)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:740)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:628)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:167)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1196)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:600)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:944)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
```

Comment: By specifying the correct channel... `channel="p2pChannel"` a channel is a channel...

Comment: @M.Deinum, I could get the queue created, but now it complains Dispatcher has no subscribers. What I want to do is to buffer the message into rabbitmq. I will have other app to consume the message, so why doesn't it complains "Dispatcher has no subscribers."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your channel `"myMessageChannel_test"` has messages from database but that needs some config like below to be able to receive/handle/subscribe to messages.

There are many ways to do it - one way as below

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnFactory" addresses="${rabbit.addresses}"
     virtual-host="${rabbit.host}" username="${rabbit.username}" password="${rabbit.password}"/> 

<rabbit:admin id="admin" connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" routing-key="some.key" exchange="some.exchange"   queue="some.queue" />   

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter routing-key="some.key" amqp-template="amqpTemplate"
        channel="myMessageChannel_test" />
```

You need to do respective rabbit configs as well